# Get the attachment file size in SharePoint list items - PnP Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I need to get the file size of each of the attachments in a SharePoint List using PnP Powershell scripting. I am able to get the attachments' file names, but not the file size.

Answer (score 0):

For file class in CSOM, you can use the length Property to estimate the file size.
PnP seems not to have property on file size.

An example here for your reference:https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/05/sharepoint-online-get-attachments-from-list-using-powershell.html

Comment: I was able to get the file size details using the below lines:   
                                          
$File = Get-PnPFile -Url $prop.ServerRelativeUrl -AsFileObject
$FileSize = [Math]::Round(($File.Length/1KB),2)

Comment: @DeekshaChotteyandamada, yes this is a good way. Thanks for your sharing